# Dynamic JTree and SwingUtilities.invokeLater() does nothing

Tags: java, swing, jtree, invokelater

To create my dynamic JTree, I was reading the tutorial about Dynamic JTrees on [this website in chapter "4.2 OutlineNode.java"](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JTree.html)

Now I have implemented it and recognize that loading the data in the GUI thread takes long and is ugly as well. Therefore I added a thread which expands the children and then adds the `TreeNode` element to the tree.

```
private void getChildNodes() {
    areChildrenDefined = true;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        System.out.println("Expand");
            final List<DECTTreeNode> listNodes = new ArrayList<DECTTreeNode>();
            if (castNode().canExpand())
            {
                for(DECTNode crt : castNode().getChildren())
                {   
                    DECTTreeNode treeNode = new DECTTreeNode(crt);
                    listNodes.add(treeNode);
                }

                try {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println(listNodes.size());
                            for (DECTTreeNode crt : listNodes)
                            {
                                add(crt); // <==== Adds the node to the JTree
                            }
                        }

                    });
                    //}).run();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

    });
    t.start();
}
```

Without the thread it works without problems. If I add the thread and put the `add`-calls into a `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(...)`, the children seem to be expanded, but they're not visible in the tree.

I've already tried `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the tree - without any effect.

Any idea how to make these elements visible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that this code did nothing, can you please to printout Nodes from TreeModel, if contains something

Comment: As mentioned: It seems to work without the threading. If I expand them and show the Nodes all in the same thread, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent e) throws ExpandVetoException {
    CustomTreeNode t = (CustomTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
    t.addChildLoadedListener(new ChildLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void childLoaded(TreeNode parent) {
            ((CustomTreeNode) parent).setExpanded(true);
            expandPath(new TreePath(((CustomTreeNode) parent).getPath()));
        }
    });
    if (!t.isExpanded()) {
        factory.loadChildren(t);
        throw new ExpandVetoException(null);
    }
}

public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent e) throws ExpandVetoException {
    CustomTreeNode t = (CustomTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
    t.setExpanded(false);
}
```

Jugde me or not. This works for me. CustomTreeNode is extended from defaultMutableTreeNode and has been added a selfwritten ChildLoadedListener which is called when the children have been loaded by the factory. The isExpanded boolean is to avoid a endless loop.
the factory creates a SwingWorker that loads the children and executes it. after that the ChilLoadedListener is called and the tree is expanded again.

Hope this will help or at least help you think about your problem ;-)

**EDIT :**

```
@Override
public void loadChildren(CustomTreeNode tn) {
    ctn = tn;
    LoadChildrenWorker worker = new LoadChildrenWorker();
    worker.execute();
}


private class LoadChildrenWorker extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {

            @Override
    protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    //load source here and return a string when finished.
                    //In my case its a string repesentation of a directory
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
            //with get(), you get the string from doBackground()
            for (String str : parseFromOutput(get())) {
                    if (str.endsWith("/")) {
                        ctn.add(new CustomTreeNode("Directory");
                    } else {
                        ctn.add(new CustomTreeNode("Leaf");
                    }
            }
            //call listeners
            ctn.fireChildrenLoaded();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you show me your `SwingWorker`'s `finished()` methode please? I somehow get a `ConcurrentModificationException` while iterating over the previously registered listeners. many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check that your add() method fires the correct TreeModelEvent

Comment: Sorry for the confusion created. The snippet in my question is part of a class that `extends DefaultMutableTreeNode`. Therefore, `add()` does what the parent, `DefaultMutableTreeNode` does.

Comment: Then that is the problem. DefaultMutableTreeNode does not fire events when add() is called. You need to add nodes through the model, see DefaultTreeModel#insertNodeInto (or manual fire the correct event).

Answer (score 3):

to expand suggestion by Walter +1, invoke `Runnable#Thread` from JButton `addButton`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.tree.*;

public class DynamicTreeDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int newNodeSuffix = 1;
    private static String ADD_COMMAND = "add";
    private static String REMOVE_COMMAND = "remove";
    private static String CLEAR_COMMAND = "clear";
    private DynamicTree treePanel;

    public DynamicTreeDemo() {
        super(new BorderLayout()); // Create the components.
        treePanel = new DynamicTree();
        populateTree(treePanel);
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
        addButton.setActionCommand(ADD_COMMAND);
        addButton.addActionListener(this);
        JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
        removeButton.setActionCommand(REMOVE_COMMAND);
        removeButton.addActionListener(this);
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        clearButton.setActionCommand(CLEAR_COMMAND);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);  // Lay everything out.
        treePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        add(treePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 3));
        panel.add(addButton);
        panel.add(removeButton);
        panel.add(clearButton);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void populateTree(DynamicTree treePanel) {
        String p1Name = "Parent 1";
        String p2Name = "Parent 2";
        String c1Name = "Child 1";
        String c2Name = "Child 2";
        DefaultMutableTreeNode p1, p2;
        p1 = treePanel.addObject(null, p1Name);
        p2 = treePanel.addObject(null, p2Name);
        treePanel.addObject(p1, c1Name);
        treePanel.addObject(p1, c2Name);
        treePanel.addObject(p2, c1Name);
        treePanel.addObject(p2, c2Name);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        if (ADD_COMMAND.equals(command)) { // Add button clicked
            treePanel.addObject("New Node " + newNodeSuffix++);
        } else if (REMOVE_COMMAND.equals(command)) { // Remove button clicked
            treePanel.removeCurrentNode();
        } else if (CLEAR_COMMAND.equals(command)) { // Clear button clicked.
            treePanel.clear();
        }
    }


    private static void createAndShowGUI() { // Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DynamicTreeDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Create and set up the content pane.
        DynamicTreeDemo newContentPane = new DynamicTreeDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);  // Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}


class DynamicTree extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
    private DefaultTreeModel treeModel;
    private JTree tree;
    private Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    public DynamicTree() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node");
        treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);
        treeModel.addTreeModelListener(new MyTreeModelListener());
        tree = new JTree(treeModel);
        tree.setEditable(true);
        tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
        tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void clear() {
        rootNode.removeAllChildren();
        treeModel.reload();
    }

    public void removeCurrentNode() {
        TreePath currentSelection = tree.getSelectionPath();
        if (currentSelection != null) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode currentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (currentSelection.getLastPathComponent());
            MutableTreeNode parent = (MutableTreeNode) (currentNode.getParent());
            if (parent != null) {
                treeModel.removeNodeFromParent(currentNode);
                return;
            }
        } // Either there was no selection, or the root was selected.
        toolkit.beep();
    }


    public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(Object child) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode parentNode = null;
        TreePath parentPath = tree.getSelectionPath();
        if (parentPath == null) {
            parentNode = rootNode;
        } else {
            parentNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (parentPath.getLastPathComponent());
        }
        return addObject(parentNode, child, true);
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object child) {
        return addObject(parent, child, false);
    }

    public DefaultMutableTreeNode addObject(DefaultMutableTreeNode parent, Object child, boolean shouldBeVisible) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(child);
        if (parent == null) {
            parent = rootNode;
        }
        // It is key to invoke this on the TreeModel, and NOT DefaultMutableTreeNode
        treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, parent, parent.getChildCount());
        // Make sure the user can see the lovely new node.
        if (shouldBeVisible) {
            tree.scrollPathToVisible(new TreePath(childNode.getPath()));
        }
        return childNode;
    }



    class MyTreeModelListener implements TreeModelListener {

        @Override
        public void treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());            /*
             * If the event lists children, then the changed node is the child of the
             * node we've already gotten. Otherwise, the changed node and the
             * specified node are the same.
             */ int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));
            System.out.println("The user has finished editing the node.");
            System.out.println("New value NodesChanged: " + node.getUserObject());
        }

        @Override
        public void treeNodesInserted(TreeModelEvent e) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node= (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());            /*
             * If the event lists children, then the changed node is the child of the
             * node we've already gotten. Otherwise, the changed node and the
             * specified node are the same.
             */ int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));
            System.out.println("New value NodesInserted : " + node.getUserObject());
        }

        @Override
        public void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());            /*
             * If the event lists children, then the changed node is the child of the
             * node we've already gotten. Otherwise, the changed node and the
             * specified node are the same.
             */ int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));
            System.out.println("New value NodesRemoved : " + node.getUserObject());
        }

        @Override
        public void treeStructureChanged(TreeModelEvent e) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (e.getTreePath().getLastPathComponent());            /*
             * If the event lists children, then the changed node is the child of the
             * node we've already gotten. Otherwise, the changed node and the
             * specified node are the same.
             */ int index = e.getChildIndices()[0];
            node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) (node.getChildAt(index));
            System.out.println("New value StructureChanged : " + node.getUserObject());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problems in the project I am working on right now.

I use an `TreeWillExpandListener`to determine when my tree has to be loaded. (LazyLoading)
When the tree expanded I catched the node an loaded it's children inside a thread, because i had to parse the nodes from a server output.

The problem you are facing is that the tree expands before your children are loaded. so you have to throw a `ExpandVetoException` or something like that and wait till your children are loaded. then expand your tree. in this case everything will show right.

Hope that will hope your problem.

Exapand-> Stop expand-> loadchildren-> addChildren -> now expand tree -> see your nodes

**EDIT :**

If you work with swing, you better use SwingWorker. Works better for me.

Comment: Even I didn't try it that way, I guess it won't work: When collapsing the node, I don't delete the content. Therefore it should be visible when collapsing and reexpanding the node again. But it's not. Or is this yet another different problem?

Comment: I had the same problem. They load the children every time the tree opens. and it opens the tree every time before you have loaded the children. `System.out.println()`is our friend ;-) (as my former teacher always said)

Comment: No offense, but even though your solution seems to work for you, I think this looks like an ugly hack? Well... as mentioned: I have a flag which ensures the children to be expanded only once. They will be kept in a list and returned...

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `invokeAndWait` with `invokeLater`.